# will 32 bit ubuntu 16.04 be wiped out if i install 64 bit ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 64-bit

I am using 32 bit ubuntu 16.04.  however a program I wish to use is only for 64 bit machines.  How may I install the 64bit ubuntu 16.04 without wiping all my current files.  I am new to this so if it is possible, could you use a step by step answer to help me overcome this problem.
I am using a desktop computer and have been told it will handle 64 bit programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to create a different partition for and alternate Operating System.  You can do this manually or allow the installer to create the new partition by splitting the space you're already using.

To do the latter, run the Install process the same way you did when you originally installed the 32bit version.  Then choose the option **Install Alongside Other OS**

The install process will give you a graphic screen where you can use a slider to determine how big for you want allocate for Linux.

Your current 32 bit installation would be over written if you choose to install on the same partition as it.  I'll overwrite the system files, but leave your `/home` folder.  This latter choice would leave you with one OS, the 64-bit version along with the files that you have in your `/home/username` folder.

The installation details from the official **Canonical Site** are [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop).

### Creating the Live boot media

Steps for creating a USB or DVD installer are below.  Some people find one of the methods easier than the other.  But they both work fine.

**Making a USB installer**

```
1: Insert the USB stick with at least 2GB of space.
2: Type Startup Disk Creator in the Ubuntu Search Button and start the Creator
   app.
3: (a) In the CD-Drive/Image field of the program select the ISO image.
   (b) In the Disk to use field select the USB device.
4: Click the Make Startup Disk button and follow the prompts.
```

Details are [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu).

**Making a DVD installer**

While there are many CD/DVD creators I use [Brasero](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=yakkety&section=all&arch=any&keywords=brasero&searchon=names).

You can install it from the repository with:

```
$ apt install brasero
```

Once installed, perform these steps:

```
1: Insert a blank DVD into the drive.
2: Type brasero in the Ubuntu Search Button and launch the app.
3: Click Burn Image
4: Select the ISO image for the Select a disk image to write field.
5: Select your Blank DVD disc for the Select a disc to write to field.
6: Click Burn and follow the prompts.
```

Comment: That was fantastic, thank you for the help. especially the step by step installation guide,

Comment: Thank you again, I didn´t know how to mark a question answered.     P.S.  I down loaded the 64 bit version as an  .ISO file and after a day of Googling I still have no idea how to make it an installable.  (.EXE)

Comment: I'll update my answer with easy steps.  Look at my answer in about 15 minutes to see the steps.

Comment: Thank you yet again L.D. James.  I would be totally lost without this step by step information from you.

Comment: All set again L.D. James,  works well and thank you.